# Let $D_{m}$ be the divisors of m. Defins inf{a,b} = gcd{a, b}, sup{a, b}= lcm{a, b}, and -d=m/d. Investgate when $D_{m}$ is a Boolean algebra.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I Was preparing for my exam and wanted to write Formal Prove,
Question:

Let $D_{m}$ be the divisors of m.  Defins inf{a,b} = gcd{a, b}, sup{a, b} = lcm{a, b}, and $¬\,d=\frac{m}{d}$ . Investgate when $D_{m}$ is a Boolean algebra.

Here is my idea:

- first I need to show that $a$ ∧ $b =$ gcd{a,b} , $a$ ∨ $b =$ lcm{a,b}  for any  $ a , b \,\,\epsilon\,\,D_{m}$ and the complement is the division  so $D_{m}$ is lattice by definition
- second, all of the boolean algebra conditions are applied except the complement so $a\,\,\,∧\,\,\,a^{`} = 0$  and  $a\,\,\,∨\,\,\,a^{`} = 1$

so if m is product distinct primes then the complement of any element $¬\,d=\frac{m}{d}$ for $d\,\,\epsilon\,\,D_{m}$ so it's boolean algebra

and if m is a product of non-distinct primes so there will be primes with no complement so it's not a boolean algebra,

I want to order my think process and write consistant mathematical prove.

Comment: [$_$ is a boolean algebra iff there is no prime $p$ such that $p^2|m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483160/d-m-is-a-boolean-algebra-iff-there-is-no-prime-p-such-that-p2-mid-m/3483840#3483840)

Comment: So you seem to be in the right track